# To prove that $X_{\infty}$ is normal

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

If $((X_n),(f_n))$ is a inverse limit system, and for each $n$, $X_n\neq 
{\emptyset}$ is compact and Hausdorff then $X_{\infty}$ is normal.

I know there is a theory that says: If $((X_n),(f_n))$ an inverse limit system , and for each $n$, $X_n\neq{\emptyset}$ is compact and Hausdorff then $X_{\infty}$ is Hausdorff and compact. So by using another theory that every compact, Hausdorff space is normal , can it be solved?

Comment: What is your definition of "reversed boundary system"?  According to Google this post is the first time that phrase has ever been written on the internet, so I'm guessing you're translating from some other language...

Comment: @EricWofsey I think "inverse limit" is meant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse limit of a system of (non-empty) compact Hausdorff spaces is again compact Hausdorff, hence normal. Yes, those two steps will do it.